# What is the relation between class and call_user_func() function in php?

Tags: php, function

I am learning to OOP in php from [php.net](http://php.net/) but in the third note on [that page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) i found a strange thing that says **If the class name is used e.g. in call_user_func() then it can contain some dangerous characters such as ../**.

According to my experience **call_user_func()** is used to call the call back provided in the first parameter. But what is the concept or relation of the class name in **call_user_func()** function, i am got confused.

Can anyone tell me the scenario ?

Comment: Class names don't have those "dangerous characters", they're potentially dangerous in filenames if they are derived from user input, but simply cannot exist in filenames; so can you show the reference where you read this

Comment: I already added the reference links in the question description.

Comment: reference link -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: You can use the `call_user_func` function to invoke a member function (method) of a class. This is done by providing the fully qualified member function name e.g. `call_user_func('Example\SomeClass::member')` or as an array `call_user_func(['Example\SomeClass', 'member'])`. You should exercise caution when providing user input as the class name string.

Comment: I wan't to give you 100000000+ votes

Comment: but it is not possible on stack overflow :(

Comment: why php.net is not documented in complete sense, why php.net confuse developers to learn php in difficult english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning must be quite old. Most (all?) dangerous characters in class names result in `__autoload` not being called. At least since late PHP 5.4.x / early 5.5.x. But before that it used to be a problem. Consider the following autoloader:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
  eval('class '.$class_name.' {}');
});
```

Obviously it's stupid by itself, but since it's only for demonstration. Combine it with the equally stupid call:

```
call_user_func(array($user_input,'function'));
```

And if `$user_input` actually comes from an evil user, or is something like:

```
$user_input = 'dummy {}echo"hi";//';
```

You have an RCE for PHP 5.3.x. But I'll admit that many mistakes were made.

[3v4al Link](https://3v4l.org/XbHMU) for those interested. Check `eol versions`, if you want to try some variations.